# Solving for eigenvectors with eigenvalue

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have an eigenvalue and I'm trying to solve for the associated eigenvector.
The equation is: $[A]*[v]=b[v]$
I have matrix $[A]$, and eigenvalue $b$.
How do I solve for matrix $[v]$?

It seems this should be simple, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Do you know how to solve a linear system of equations?

Answer (score 0):

suppose that

$A*v=k*v$

where  $k$ is eigenvalue,then it satisfy

$det(A-k*I)=0$

after that put values of $k$,could you continue?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations

Comment: The sys of linear eq's did it for me.  Simple substitution gave me the vector.  The det()=0 didn't help me at all.  i.e. I'm not sure how this helps.  Maybe you ment: (A-kI)v=0